# Threads , [WebSocket & nodejs] vs [asp.net & signalR] clarification?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, websocket, scalability, signalr

In a situation where a  ---

- Client connects to an asp.net (*which uses the signalR FW*) and upgrades the  connection to a webSocket connection(tcp)

or

- Client connects to a `Node.js` server (and also upgrades the connection)

Question :

If the server now wants to initiate  message sending , does it *dedicate a new thread* to do it ? because if it does , I can't see how `signalR`||`Node.js` is scalable because sending a message to a 100K users , can crash the system.

or am I missing something :-) ?

Comment: node will use only one thread by default. If you have the resources, you use a `cluster` of node instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SignalR the number of threads has no correlation to the number of sockets open to clients.

So answer is **No**.